# How to use Grep + cut + sort with Colour

Tags: bash, grep

I am running a command on watch to monitor logins on the mail server (Recent Compromise)

It works fine, just ideally i wanted to colour code a specific IP Address so i can easily see any IP addresses connecting not from an internal IP address.

The command i am running:

```
grep -Hrn "Login:" /var/log/maillog | cut -d ' ' -f 8,10 | sort -u
```

With watch:

```
watch "grep -Hrn "Login:" /var/log/maillog | cut -d ' ' -f 8,10 | sort -u"
```

How can i highlight s specific IP address with a specific colour. for example

The output is like this:

```
user=<Email1@Doamin.co.uk>, rip=123.123.123.123,
user=<Email1@Doamin.co.uk>, rip=321.321.321.321,
user=<Email2@Doamin.co.uk>, rip=123.123.123.123,
user=<Email2@Doamin.co.uk>, rip=111.111.111.111,
user=<Email3@Doamin.co.uk>, rip=123.123.123.123,
user=<Email4@Doamin.co.uk>, rip=123.123.123.123,
user=<Email4@Doamin.co.uk>, rip=198.1987.198.198,
user=<Email4@Doamin.co.uk>, rip=81.81.81.81,
```

Lets say the internal IP address is: 123.123.123.123
How can i get the output to auto colour code that IP address.

People work off site and also have emails on there mobile, i would expect to see a few different IP addresses from the same Email address, but if we have a full house, generally everyone connects on Wifi and devices on the same network, just wanted it for easy viewing

**UPDATE**

Based on a few answers below, it was the -c needed in Watch and the grep -z to highlight results but not alter the output.

```
watch -c "grep -Hrn --color=always "Login:" /var/log/maillog | grep --color=always -z "123.123.123.123" | cut -d ' ' -f 8,10 | sort -u"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add option `-c` (interpret ANSI color and style sequences) to your `watch` command and `--color=always` to your GNU `grep` command.

Comment: Thanks it was the -z command i needed. Just added another piped grep with -z. 
watch -c "grep -Hrn --color=always "Login:" /var/log/maillog | grep --color=always -z "123.123.123.123" | cut -d ' ' -f 8,10 | sort -u"

Answer (score 0):

Try using grep with `--color='always'` and match it with your **IP-ADRESSE** or a Regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=$(somecommand)
red="\e[31m" #or other color codes
echo -e "${red}$a"
```